# CakePHP 3.x - One form data to be saved in many tables

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm working on a Cake PHP 3 project and I'm having a problem:

In my database there are: `users (id,...)`, `people (id,user_id,...)` and `clients (id,person_id,...)`, all one-to-one relation.

I've set all relations in the `UsersTable`, `PeopleTable` and `ClientsTable` classes, on `initialize` method.

In `Templates/Clients/new.ctp`, I'm using Form helper with `<fieldname>`, `person.<fieldname>` and `person.user.<fieldname>` in the inputs for **client**, **person** and **user** data respectively.

In `ClientsController::new()`, when I try to save data, Cake is throwing an error because it tries to save in the `clients` table first, but there is no `people` data yet, so constraint for `person_id` fails.

How can I tell Cake to, from `ClientsController`, save data first on `users`, then on `people` and then on `client` table?

Comment: It's advised to show the corresponding code too instead of just describing the picture, as in the world of programming, code is worth more than peoples words. The code would answer the following question: Have you properly defined the other side associations too, ie the `belongsTo` ones?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the associated models when patching/saving as you have nested associations.

```
$this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $this->request->data, [
    'associated' => [
        'People.Users'
    ]
]);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities

Answer (score 0):

I solved it saving data from **users** perspective. In `ClientsController::new()`:

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$client = $users->newEntity( $this->request->data(), [
    'associated' => [
        'People',
        'People.Clients'
    ]
]);
```

And now in `Templates/Clients/new.ctp` I'm using Form helper with `<fieldname>`, `person.<fieldname>` and `person.client.<fieldname>` in the inputs for **user**, **person** and **client** data respectively.

Thanks a lot for the guys from `irc.freenode.org` `#cakephp`